# When electrons move from the p-type to the wire

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I have a question about why electrons can move from the p-type to the wire.

Is it correct to say that when we have a p-n diode and we have a forward bias, the electrons can move from the p-type to the wire because the energy level of the valence band in the p-type is overlapping of the energy level of the valence band in the metal in the wire?

Comment: For an ohmic contact, yes, there is overlap without any potential barriers.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you very much.